# Add local name to computers on Windows Server 2016 with DHCP / DNS / AD

Tags: dns, dhcp, active-directory, windows-server

I'm migrating my server from Ubuntu with dnsmasq to Windows 2016 Server.

I managed to assign static ip to computers using their MAC adress with the DHCP server.

What i'd like to do, as previously with dnsmasq (using dhcp-option=MAC-ADRESS,name,ip) is to assign a local name to a machine so i can easily have access to it on my lan.

I don't know how to do this : do i have to create an entry in DNS server or do i have to add a machine to active directory which will then update the DNS server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are options. Keep in mind, that in Windows, the Hostname (aka PC name) is always accessible.

So lets say you have a pc named MyPC with IP Address 192.168.1.56

You can obviously ping by IP Address. You can add a DNS entry manually or join the pc to a domain so the domain controller creates that DNS entry but you can also just ping MyPC directly.

Note that when you add a DNS entry and work with a domain, the DNS will be something like: mypc.domain.local which translates to that ip address, and of course mypc will also still work.

The difference is of course that with a custom DNS entry, you do not actually have to (re)name the PC itself, which is something you have to do on the pc side.

Do note, that if the pc itself has a firewall installed, it may block ping messages, so even though it works, it may appear not to be if you ping the pc or otherwise try to access it.